# Autorun VBA to Autorefresh all datasources

Tags: vba, autorun

I've been trying to put together the below to automatically start when opening the workbook and refresh all datasources every minute. Can someone help on where I've gone wrong?

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Public Const cRunIntervalMinutes = 1
Public Const cRunWhat = "Workbook_RefreshAll"
End Sub
Sub Workbook_RefreshAll()
    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you have some time please read the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). :)
I don't quite understand your question, could you please elaborate on it:
Where/How do you use `cRunIntervalMinutes` and `cRunWhat`? Is it not working at all or do you get an error message? Is that all of your code or just a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really stated what the error is, but I do not have enough points to comment so here is a solution that might work:

```
Sub Auto_Open()

    Application.CalculateFullRebuild

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```